# How to dictate a global variable in specific karma test block

Tags: karma-runner, webpack, karma-mocha

I'm trying to write a test in Karma for a react/webpack application that tests conditionals depending on global variable `__CLIENT__` being false or not.

How do I go about making it true for one it block, and then false for another? I tried setting `global.__CLIENT__`, but the console.logs from my module return true regardless of what I try to set it to in my tests.

How do I do this, hopefully in a way that keeps just one file and can be dictated in each test case. That avoids the karma.conf....

Answer (score 1):

Probably won't help you now but maybe for others:

you need to create global.js file for example and within karma webpack files add it at the start of "files"

```
files: [
    './tests/global-variables.js',
    {pattern: 'src/**/*-spec.js', watch: false}
],
```

And within global-variables.js:

```
var global = {
___CLIENT___: "some data"
}
```

Good luck!